# Oledb não funciona em outras máquinas

Tags: oledb

Fiz um aplicativo WPF e em determinado momento ele deve ler um arquivo Excel. Fiz isso por meio de Oledb. O arquivo está na mesma pasta do aplicativo.
O aplicativo funciona perfeitamente comigo mas não conecta ao Excel quando executado por outro usuário.
O aplicativo está em uma pasta no servidor.
Primeiro pensei que poderia ser algo relacionado à versão do office (vi muitos casos na internet), mas a versão é igual pra todo mundo, 32 bits.
Detalhe: não dá nenhuma mensagem de erro, simplesmente não acontece nada.

```
string arquivo = "Indices.xlsx";
string stringConnection = @"Provider=Microsoft.ACE.OLEDB.12.0;Data Source=" + arquivo + ";Extended Properties='Excel 12.0 Macro;HDR=YES'";
OleDbConnection conexao = new OleDbConnection(stringConnection);
                OleDbDataAdapter adapter = new OleDbDataAdapter("select * from [Planilha1$]", conexao);
AbrirArquivoIndices(arquivo, conexao, adapter, tabelaIndices);
adapter.Dispose();
conexao.Dispose();

private void AbrirArquivoIndices(string arquivo, OleDbConnection conexao, OleDbDataAdapter adapter, DataTable tabelaIndices)
{
    
    try {
        
        conexao.Open();
        adapter.Fill(tabelaIndices);
    
    } catch (Exception) {
        
        throw new Exception("Não foi possível obter os índices para atualização.");
    
    } finally {
        
        conexao.Close();
    }
}
```